# WordPress archive index page

Tags: customization, templates, page-template, archives

I am trying to create a custom archive index page for a custom post type.
I can't get it to work, I have followed this guide: https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Archive_Index.

Here's what I have been trying:

*1. Created a custom post type:*

```
function references(){
    register_post_type('cows',
     [
         'labels'       => [
             'name'          => __('Cows'),
             'singular_name' => __('Cow'),
         ],
         'public'       => true,
         'has_archive'  => true,
         'supports'     => ['title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'],
         'rewrite'      => array(
           'slug'       => 'cows'
         ),
     ]
    );
}
add_action('init', 'references');
```

*2. Created a `archive-cows.php` page for all the custom post type's posts.*

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();
    the_title();
        //
        // Post Content here
        //
    } // end while
} // end if
```

*3. Created a template called Cows in file: `cows.php`*

```
  /*
    Template name: Cows
  */

  get_header();

  wp_get_archives(array(
    'type' => 'monthly',
    'post_type' => 'cows',
  ));
get_footer();
```

*4. Created a new page (backend) and assigned it to template: Cows*

At the moment WordPress is loading `archive-cows.php` (because post type slug: cows and page template slug: cows), where I would like it to load `cows.php` template file, and then in that template load the archives for cows (would not like to use a custom query without a archive page).

Comment: You should add a loop about all posts from your custom post type inside the cows.php template. Thats create a list if all posts from this post type and list theme. see https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/165793/custom-loop-for-custom-post-type

Comment: Isn't best practice to use a archive-something.php to list all of the desired posts? If a user visites domain.dk/custom-post-archive-slug it would be blank if use of template file? :)

Comment: This template is for a view on a archive, not in a best practice to reference inside a template.

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter passed to `register_post_type` is the post type key which is used by the theme template hierarchy. [register_post_type documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type).

The `cows.php` is a page template, so to use it create a new page and select the 'Cows' template. You will need to alter the slug of this page so it doesn't conflict with the existing `www.example/cows` of the post type archive page.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to change register_post_type from references to cows, in this example. Locally I use another setup. Hope this isn't misleading. It's edited now. So with the current edited setup it is not working :)

Comment: Hmm. It doesn't seems to work. I can't get wordpress to display a custom index archive page, and then all the post for the archive/post-type. It's the wp_get_archives function that I can't get to work properly I think.

Comment: To confirm, you need to view the page, not the post type archive. Eg. `www.example.com/your-page-slug` not `www.example.com/cows`. Also, you'll need to be running WordPress 4.4 or above to use the `post_type` parameter in `wp_get_archives`